# Open file in Silverlight doesn't work while OpenRead works

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, file-io

**In-browser application.**

I have a standard code for opening Open File Dialog, then reading file using `dlg.File.OpenRead()`. Now the problem comes if that file is opened with Excel. The opening failed, because internally it does following:

```
public FileStream OpenRead()
{
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, this.FullPath).Assert();
    return new FileStream(this.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, false);
}
```

To access file opened in Excel you have to use `FileShare.ReadWrite`. Ok, there is `Open` method, so I write:

```
dlg.File.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```

And it gives error: "File operation not permitted. Access to path 'xyz' is denied". I checked what `Open` does internally:

```
public FileStream Open(FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
{
    return new FileStream(this.FullPath, mode, access, share);
}
```

Almost the same except requesting `FileIOPermission`, which in turn is internal and you can't use it in code.

So the question is, how to make this `Open` work? Or how can you open file with `ReadWrite` sharing?

Comment: Is this an OOB app or in-browser?

Comment: @Christopher Estep in-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: you can't.   The `OpenFileDialog` will only give you read access to the file in question.   Similarly the `SaveFileDialog` only gives you write access.  You don't get to control the level of sharing so you can't specify share ReadWrite.

You will need to ask the user to close the Excel file first before continuing as part of handling this error.

Comment: It is really strange that one can't control level of sharing. Another workaround is to use HTML form to submit file to server and process it there and send results back to SL.